# Windows 7: sniff TCP sockets to localhost

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, localhost

I want to capture and analyze TCP communication data between two applications running on local host, which is running Windows 7 OS.  I try to use Wireshark, but Wireshark could not capture the data, it seems just monitor the data in/out the network interface.

Could you introduce some useful tools to monitor the local TCP data easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason wireshark doesn't work is because  sniffers rely on the network driver stack, and Windows don't expose `localhost` calls through it.

You should use [Socket Sniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html), which looks at Winsock calls and monitors network sockets; the download link is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Note that SocketSniffer does not support 64 bit applications at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations in Windows that prevent libpcap and Microsoft Network Monitor from sniffing localhost/loopback. But you can sniff localhost if you use Raw Sockets.

There is a free tool called [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) that can sniff localhost and save the captured packets in a PCAP file. This allows you to inspect the traffic in Wireshark later on.

You can download RawCap from here:
http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap

Comment: RawCap + opening in Wireshark worked fine for me, today. SocketSniffer above — it didn't listen the processes I wanted to sniff on though, didn't work for me.